# Reload scheduledExecutorService without reloading of server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduledexecutorservice

I have this class:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyScheduler {

    @Value("${scheduler.count}")
    private int SCHEDULER_COUNT;//for example 5

    private final SendRequestForResponseService sendRequestForResponseService;

    public MyScheduler(SendRequestForResponseService sendRequestForResponseService) {
        this.sendRequestForResponseService = sendRequestForResponseService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void getRequestResponse() {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(SCHEDULER_COUNT, new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler());
        for (int i = 0; i < SCHEDULER_COUNT; i++) {
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(sendRequestForResponseService::sendGetResponseRequest, 1, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

After server start, I create `ScheduledExecutorService` with `corePoolSize` value from propertyes(SCHEDULER_COUNT) and start SCHEDULER_COUNT times. Now I have 5 schedulers that trigger each 1 NANOSECONDS.

Now I need mechanizm for change `SCHEDULER_COUNT` in property and re-run  `ScheduledExecutorService` with new cont(for example 10) and not restart server. is it possible any ideas?

One of the ideas is to write a rest service which will reload from the value and restart the scheduler. but that's in theory

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to retain your scheduler so you can cancel the previous tasks:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyScheduler {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;

    @Value("${scheduler.count}")
    private int SCHEDULER_COUNT;//for example 5

    private final SendRequestForResponseService sendRequestForResponseService;

    public MyScheduler(SendRequestForResponseService sendRequestForResponseService) {
        this.sendRequestForResponseService = sendRequestForResponseService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void getRequestResponse() {
        setCount(env.getProperty("", Integer.class, 5);
    }

    public void setCount(int newCount) {
        if (scheduledExecutorService != null) {
            scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
        }
        scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(SCHEDULER_COUNT, new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler());
        int schedulerCount = newCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < schedulerCount; i++) {
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay
                (sendRequestForResponseService::sendGetResponseRequest, 1, 1,
                                                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `setCount` could then be done with a REST service, yes.